# How can I flush the output of disp in Matlab or Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, flush, disp

I have a program in Octave that has a loop - running a function with various parameters, not something that I can turn into matrices.  At the beginning of each iteration I print the current parameters using `disp`.

The first times I ran it I had a [brazillion](http://politicalhumor.about.com/library/jokes/bljokebushbrazilian.htm) warnings, and then I also got these prints.  Now that I cleaned them up, I no longer see them.  My guess is that they're stuck in a buffer, and I'll see them when the program ends or the buffer fills.

Is there any way to force a flush of the print buffer so that I can see my prints?

Comment: Here's more, including info on paging: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/octave/octave_22.html

Comment: Does it happen in Matlab as well?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use fflush(stdout) and/or fflush(stderr) to flush the buffer from disp().

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there's a Matlab equivalent to fflush()? I'd like to do the same thing, but I use Matlab, not Octave, and there's no fflush() function.

Comment: In MATLAB, use `drawnow('update')` to flush the output.

Answer (score 30):

As mentioned by moastab, `fflush(stdout)` works for Octave.

In MATLAB, use `drawnow('update')` to flush the output.

MATLAB's `drawnow` function will be familiar to those who control the redrawing of graphical objects in MATLAB, but it applies to the stdout stderr buffers as well. The `'update'` option is not required, but limits the flushing to non-graphical queues. This detail is merely implied in the [drawnow() documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html); I have verified it to work on fprintf calls in a loop.

Answer (score 21):

**Octave**: You can turn off buffering of output by calling `more off`.

This will disable pagination such that all output is sent directly to the screen.

Answer (score 7):

Put the following commands at the beginning of your section or your code:

```
page_screen_output(0);

page_output_immediately(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use **diary** function to dump all session output to a text file. `diary on` will start recording, and `diary off` will stop. `diary filename` will use filename instead of default "diary".

It is build -in function in both Octave and MATLAB. For more details see `help diary`.

---

Also you can increase Octave buffer size. On Windows you can do it in Octave Properties dialog from upper left corner menu.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/octave/octave_22.html) and elsewhere, there are at least 5 methods to get immediate output, in *Octave*.

Use **one** of the following:

```matlab
%---------------------------
% Turn OFF output buffering
%---------------------------
more off                        % command & NOT shown in output
PAGER = "less"                  % built-in var - shown in output
page_screen_output = 0          % built-in var - shown in output
page_output_immediately = 1     % built-in var - shown in output
fflush(stdout)                  % Need to call after each "output" line
```

Answer (score 0):

`drawnow` will cause graphs to update, I'm not sure if it works on the `stdout` pipe as well.

You might also convert your `disp(...)` statements to `fprintf(stderr, ...)`, I think `stderr` is handled differently from `stdout` on Octave.