# octave large data set, doesn't disp() or write properly

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a huge data set that I'm caching, then writing filtered analysis data to disk.  I have various `disp()` commands in my code, along with `fprintf()` calls.

I'd like to see the results both in the file, and on the screen while the processes are running, but what I'm finding is that I get nothing until I terminate the program, at which point all the data is written into my file and the `disp()` floods the terminal.

Would there be a way to force `disp()` and the `fprintf()` to execute as they're being processed??

Here's an example:

```
function one(varargin)
    setenv GNUTERM 'x11';

    dirname = strcat(pwd, '/fileset');
    files = dir(dirname);
    disp('reading directory'), disp(dirname);
    fileidx = find(~[files.isdir]);
    out = fopen('write_data.txt', 'w');
    fprintf(out, '"--- var a[0]", "--- var [1]";\n');

    numfiles = length(fileidx);
    for i = 1:numfiles
        dispstring = sprintf('processing file %d of %d...', i, numfiles);
        disp(dispstring);
        filename = [dirname, '/', files(fileidx(i)).name];
        disp(filename);
        fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

        %some processing here to obtain timevalues and maxvars

        for i = 1:length(timevalues)
            fprintf(out, '%d, %d;\n', timevalues(i), maxvars(i));
        end 
    end 

    fclose(out);
end
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633019/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-disp-in-matlab-or-octave), but I wasn't sure which of the methods suggested applied to me.  It also seemed like `fflush()` was meant for pushing data into a plot at higher priority.

Comment: where would you put the pause? i was thinking at the end of the for loop that prints...

Comment: If you had posted it as a solution, I could confirm it.  Aside from that, I need more details on what you would do.  Feel free to post an actual answer...  Thx

Comment: Though someone already upvoted it I guess I just had to delete my answer (`pause` didn't help). Don't know what else could do the trick, perhaps switching to Matlab?

Comment: Switching to Matlab is not an option due to the difference in price (free vs. thousands of dollars).

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before and you do you fflush to solve it. Write

```
fflush(stdout);
```

to force the terminal to be updated with the results of all the prints and disps to stdout that came before the call to fflush(stdout). I'm not sure if you should bother flushing the output to the file as it will probably make your code slower, but if you want to you can do

```
fflush(out);
```

Comment: thanks.  I will be checking this out within a day or so; I really appreciate your input and have a feeling that this may in fact work out.  BTW- would I use *both* `fflush(stdout)` and `fflush(out)` ?

Comment: fflush(stdout) to force the terminal to be updated with results and fflush(out) to force the update to your file. You would have to do both if you want both the terminal and file to be updated inside the for loop.