# How to make GNU Octave auto-flush results while running the script

Tags: printf, echo, octave

While a script function is running, the results produced by `fprintf` or `disp` commands do not show in the terminal, only when the execution ends (or it is stopped) then they all appear. `fflush` solves the problem, but it's tedious to use after each print. Is there any way to auto-flush to the terminal?

Using version 3.8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I flush the output of disp in Matlab or Octave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633019/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-disp-in-matlab-or-octave)

Comment: Here, the discussion seems to point also towards graphics. My question is how to activate the auto-flush behavior that I used to have in former versions, and Matlab.

Comment: The discussion in that question may appear to talk about graphics because the same function flushes graphical and io buffers in Matlab. I assure you it discusses the exact issue you are having.

Comment: I think you're right, the same answer has been given here. If there's no new contributions that could enrich the discussion in the other question, I will delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatically flush stuff automatically, set:

```
page_output_immediately (1);
```

and to send it to stdout without a pager, set:

```
page_screen_output (0);
```

The Octave manual has a section on this subject, [Paging Screen Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have two main options:

1. Call `fflush(stdout())` after each print.
2. Print to [`stderr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/C_002dStyle-I_002fO-Functions.html#XREFstderr) instead of [`stdout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/C_002dStyle-I_002fO-Functions.html#XREFstdout) if your system auto-flushes `stderr` (e.g. Linux).

Option 1 is generally better because it is less system dependent. Either solution can easily be wrapped in your own print function using [`varargin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Variable_002dlength-Argument-Lists.html#Variable_002dlength-Argument-Lists):

```
function n = my_print(varargin)
    n = fprintf(stdout(), varargin{:});
    fflush(stdout());
end
```

Comment: That means typing annoying `fflush` commands all around. I'm using Linux, my original question was more on how to make the system auto-flush. I'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: Printing to `stderr` solves the problem for the `fprintf` command in my system. Don't know if `disp` can also send to `stderr`, in principle, it does not work.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping fprintf() in a function of your own to ensure that fflush() is called. This preserves the meaning of stderr and allows you to hide stdout if you wish by piping to null.

Comment: @RyanTennill. That is an excellent suggestion. I have incorporated it in my answer.